# Do Android phones require a data connection to work?

Tags: data-connection, mobile-data, oneplus-one

I'm looking at buying a new phone, the oneplus one specifically(pre-orders open again November 17) and my current phone plan I do not have data, just calling and texting, and I was wondering if the oneplus one works without data and I could just use wifi, or if I would need to purchase a data plan for the phone to work. so it would be as simple as putting the sim card from my current phone into the oneplus one and done? all help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Only thing I would be careful of is if your current "plan" will use data on a PAYG basis when outside of your plan? If it does and this is expensive then you can turn "mobile-data" off in settings (so that it only connects on WiFi).

Answer (score 10):

No. You don't need a data connection plan to use OnePlus One or any android phone for that matter. Calling and texting will work irrespective of internet connection.
However, having a data connection will be useful if you want to use some apps on the go.

Comment: Just to clarify, using _data_ on WiFi is perfectly OK and doesn't require a mobile-data plan.

Comment: so I can just disable "mobile-data" and I would be fine and I would not use any?

Comment: Yupp. That's what I do on my test devices if they have a SIM inserted.

Answer (score 0):

You will not need a data connection to use any Android phone. Wifi can do most of the things a data connection will do and more.  But sending pictures/video/audio via texts will not work unless you have data.